# How to add css class on body [Magento2]

Tags: magento2

I am trying to add a css class on body tag but not able to find any file, from where the body tag is rendered.

I need to add one css class on body tag such as others are coming  > 
page-with-filter page-products page-layout-2columns-left **myclasshere**

in previous version below was the xml code to add class on body.

```
<reference name="root">
    <action method="addBodyClass">
        <classname>my-profile</classname>
    </action>
</reference>
```

I tried using this but it didn't worked.

I need to add one class with `page-layout-2columns-left` template only.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

In your layout or template file, you need to add an attribute to the body tag, like this:

```
<body>
    <attribute name="class" value="my-css-class"/>
    ...
```

Hope that Helps

Comment: Thanks Dave, now it is appearing on all pages, I just want this class which have layout of page-layout-2columns-left

Comment: Can't think of a way you'd easily achieve that with layout alone, other than targeting each page handle that uses 2column-left as a layout, much the same as M1.

Comment: I was just thinking to add the same lines in 2-columns-left.xml so this will target only this layout but its not working.

Comment: I just added the same on category.xml and it worked, thanks :)

Comment: how to add only for login user?

Answer (score 3):

In case you want to add a dynamic variable, eg. Store Code to the body class, you can take a look at the following example I made: https://github.com/samgranger/StoreCodeBodyClass