# Blank "column main" if static block only on CMS Page

Tags: magento2

I created a CMS Page, where I included a ".phtml" file with block-->Widget.

On that CMS Page, I only have that ".phtml" file pulling in and no other content at all.

Now there is a blank "column main" div on that CMS page. How can I remove this?

The "Column main" shouldn't even be there, if there is no content in it..

[image]

Comment: why do you want remove column-main ?  You can hide it by css in case empty content

Comment: Yea I could hide it with ":empty" but, the problem is column-main always has content even if its "empty" there is an "display:none; div inside and a hidden input.. What should I do to hide it?

Comment: U can remove using jQuery javascript in ur .phtml file if u want

Comment: Hmm.. Isnt there a better maybe full css solution? But how would it work with jquer js? :)

Comment: how does your page content look like

Comment: I think in your case you need custom page template (like 1columnt.phtml, 2columns-left.phtml etc...) And use it in your CMS page

Comment: Yea, that may be it. I think the page layout "column 1" includes that "column main" div which is a blank square, if you dont have any content in it... How should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You should not remove that div because it has form_key hidden input inside. If you remove this, your add to cart and login might not work for this page. Magento does not validate post request without a form key.  What's the problem with display:none for main content of cms page. Just do it with precision so nothing else overridden it

Comment: How can I do "display:none" ONLY for that home-page?  Looks like the column main is in "1 column" layout. So in my ".phtml" file I cannot make "display:none;" since that div is not coming from there. The blank column main div is coming from layout "1 column"..

Comment: Add a body class to your cms page only. Refer this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/104065/40851

Comment: I dont understand. I have a "blank" cms page which has "1 column" as its layout. then I have a block which includes the "homepage.phtml" file and display options as 1 column and show on cms home page.

Comment: Paste your layout in your question

Comment: I use the default "column1" layout currently. But i do not have any content on the site and only a block (.phtml page), thats why there is a blank div "column main" from that layout "column1".

Answer (score 0):

If you go back into your CMS page editor and view the HTML, can you see this div?

If not is this div inside the .phtml file you are including?

If not, check the page template/design you are using for that page such (e.g. 1 column) and take a look in that template file as it may be a wrapper in that template which is obviously outside your editable code in the CMS page.